# How do you overwrite a child row in the widget treeview?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to overwrite a child within a parent in the treeview table.
A method which I have tried is to delete and insert the new child row but after a running the code I get the error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: Item I003 I004 I005 I006 not found
```

Deleting and inserting new children works about 5 times before I get this error. From what I can figure, once all the children have been added and deleted once I get the error above. It is like the iid isn't reset once they are deleted.

I need to either select a specific child and overwrite it or delete a child and insert a new one in its place..

This is some of my code where I am getting the children within the selected tab, deleting them and inserting a new one.

```
tree_select = tree.focus()
clear_tree_children = tree.get_children(tree_select)

clear_tree_children = tree.get_children(tree_select)
        if len(clear_tree_children) > 0:
            for child in clear_tree_children:
                tree.delete(clear_tree_children)
                print(child)

if tree_phys.get() == 1:
            disPhys = ("", "", "", "", "", "Physical Disability")
            tree.insert(parent=tree_select, index=END, values=disPhys)
```

Has anyone got any ideas or other methods on how I can resolve this?

Thanks, Jacob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is like the iid isn't reset once they are deleted.

Yes, exactly, tkinter generates the defaults iid incrementally without caring whether some of the previous items have been deleted. If you need to delete/insert items and still be able to access them with the same iids, then you should assign yourself the iid when creating the items:

```
tree.insert(parent, index, my_iid, values=...)
```

JacksonPro's answer works very well if you only want to change the value in a given cell. However, if you want to change the whole row at once, you can use

```
tree.item(iid, values=new_values, text=new_text)
```

Here is an example where the whole row is changed when double-clicking on it:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from random import randrange

def click(event):
    iid = tree.focus()  # get selected item
    tree.item(iid, text='%s - reset' % iid, values=[0, 0])

columns = ['col1', 'col2']
root = tk.Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=columns)
for col in columns:
    tree.heading(col, text=col)
tree.pack()

for i in range(10):
    tree.insert('', 'end', 'item%i' % i, text='item%i' % i, values=[randrange(0, 10) for c in columns])

tree.bind('<Double-1>', click)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overwrite a selected row you can use `.set(iid, column, value)`

Here is an example code that I made a while back (double-click on any row):

```
from tkinter import ttk 
import tkinter as tk 

titles={'Id': [1,2,3,4,5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'Names':['Tom', 'Rob', 'Tim', 'Jim', 'Kim', 'Kim', 'Kim', 'Kim', 'Kim']}

def update(selected_index_iid, changed):
    index = treev.index(selected_index_iid)# or just index = treev.index(treev.selection())

    treev.set(selected_index_iid, 1, changed) # updating the tree
    titles['Names'][index] = changed  #updating the dictionary
    print(titles)

def clicked(event):
    global titles
    top = tk.Toplevel(window)

    label = tk.Label(top, text='Update: ')
    label.pack()

    entry = tk.Entry(top)
    entry.insert(0, treev.set(treev.selection())['1']) #if you only specify the iid 'set' will return dict of items, ['1'] is to select 1st column
    entry.pack()

    button= tk.Button(top, text='Update', command=lambda :update(treev.selection(), entry.get()))
    button.pack()
    
    
  
window = tk.Tk() 

treev = ttk.Treeview(window, selectmode ='browse')
treev.bind('<Double-Button-1>', clicked)

treev.pack(side='left',expand=True, fill='both') 
  

verscrlbar = ttk.Scrollbar(window,  
                           orient ="vertical",  
                           command = treev.yview) 
  
verscrlbar.pack(side ='right', fill ='y')   
treev.configure(yscrollcommand = verscrlbar.set) 

treev["columns"] = list(x for x in range(len(list(titles.keys()))))
treev['show'] = 'headings'

  
for x, y in enumerate(titles.keys()):
    treev.column(x, minwidth=20, stretch=True,  anchor='c')
    treev.heading(x, text=y)

for args in zip(*list(titles.values())):
    treev.insert("", 'end', values =args) 

window.mainloop()
```